# Difference in Python Global Variable Scoping

Tags: python, scope, global

What is the difference between a variable that has been scoped using the global keyword in python vs. a globally defined variable?

From my tests there doesn't seem to be any difference. The only real difference I see is that semantically the global keyword can scope a variable to the global level where as globally defining a variable is just that, scoped globally.

My Test:

```
tmpDict = {}
class functions:
    def dictionary(self):
        global my_dict 
        my_dict= {}
        global keys_list 
        keys_list = []
        for i in range(3):
            my_dict.__setitem__(str(i),i)
            tmpDict.__setitem__(str(i),i)
            keys_list.append(str(i))
fun = functions()
fun.dictionary()
print(tmpDict)
print(my_dict)
```

Test Output:
[image]

I guess what I'm trying to ask is, If they do the same thing (make a global variable) then why would you ever use the global keyword to do that?

Comment: If you have a global scoped variable outside, and if you want to mutate it inside a function scope, you have to use the global keyword - 1 use

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. The `global` statement does exactly one thing: it makes the following name(s) be treated as if they were in the global scope, rather than the local scope. The only reason you need a declaration for `my_dict` and not `tmpDict` is that you *assign* to the name `my_dict` in the local scope, which would make it a local variable without the `global my_dict`.